# Find the value of a such that the area bound between the curves $e^{(ax^2)}$ and $e^{1/8}$ and the lines x = 0 and x= 1 is minimum

Tags: definite-integrals

> Find the value of a such that the area bound between the curves $e^{(ax^2)}$ and $e^{1/8}$ and the lines x = 0 and x= 1 is minimum

I found out the point of intersection $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2a}}$ then found out the area after that used Newton lebnitz theorem and differentiated the function with respect to $a$. The issue I'm facing is that the final term I have to solve to obtain the value of a is of the form $$x^2 e^{x^2}$$

Comment: How did you obtain $a$ of that form?

Comment: What about area, question seems to lack something.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit fixed it

Comment: The area you are integrating over is not bound by the line $x=0$. In fact those curves and lines bound two distinct areas. I would say the question is ambiguous; are you meant to take the sum of the two areas? It's no good integrating $e^{ax^2}-e^{1/8}$ from $0$ to $1$, because that gives you the difference of the areas. So you have to be careful.